# getting undefined data when submitting HTML form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

https://pasteboard.co/IVAyRyij.png

I'm trying to send form data to PHP but I just get undefined as form data. Please help.

My HTML:

```
<div class="account-wall">
    <img class="profile-img" src="img/male.png" alt="">
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" ng-submit="login('Restraunt')">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user" placeholder="User Name" required >
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
        <label class="checkbox pull-left">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
        </label>
        <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

My ui-view:

```
.state("app.admin", {
    url: "/admin",
    views: {
        sub: {
            templateUrl: "templates/admin.html"
        }
    }
})
```

My Controllers:

```
$scope.login=function (type2) {
        $http2.post($rootScope.url+"login.php",{
            type:type2,
            user:$scope.user,
            pass:$scope.pass
        }).then(function (resp)
```

Comment: Input name="" missing?

Comment: Is `$http2.post` a typo?

Comment: What does the Network Tab of the Developer Console show?